# Why does the .net world not have application servers like the Java world?

Tags: .net, application-server

I know about IIS being the web/application server. Why not have full fledge enterprise application servers like Web Logic / Tomcat / JBoss that are so scalable like they have in Java world.

EDIT1: I am not a Java developer myself. I called those servers only because "scalable and configurable and optimized" are the buzz words associated with them in most places I read about them. Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627507/what-is-scalable-fast-application-server-to-use-for-developing-services-written) on stack overflow for example. I am not jealous, just curious

Comment: I've often wondered the exact same thing. Curious to see what people think.

Comment: Is it really appropriate to compare COM+ to Java server applications?

Comment: @John: Please see my edit and please expand.

Comment: I'm not a Java developer -- What makes WebLogic/Tomcat/JBoss scalable that IIS doesn't have?

Comment: @Paul: COM+ includes most of the features that you refer to as buzzwords, and I believe it had them first. It's even fairly easy to create a COM+ application in .NET languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly because the Java world tries to be vendor independant, and platform independant it needs a coherent specification and execution environment for server side development - and that ended up beeing j2ee.

.NET on the other hand is all Microsoft - so they can provide the whole stack. Windows itself , libraries , frameworks etc. (IIS,WCF,COM to mention a few) is really the .NET version of a j2ee server.

Comment: And I think, more to the point, the first releases of Java had none of these features - just the JVM and libraries. "Java Application Servers" needed to be added in order to provide this missing functionality. The name for "those products that add the missing functionality" is "Application Server". The Windows Server /.NET platform didn't need this functionality added in the same shapes and sizes, so it can look like something's missing when in fact, it was there from day 1.

Comment: One difference being, with Java, you have a good *free* option (Tomcat). With .NET, you get to pay for IIS.

Comment: @John: Talking specifically of services(remoting/WCF) running on non-http protocols, would it not be viable to have an application server for that purpose. These java application servers have so many options for configurable workflows etc. Isnt COM+ a technology of yesterday (asking genuinely)??

Comment: @Perpetualcoder: yesterday is good enough to the extent that today is no different from yesterday. For tomorrow, see http://www.microsoft.com/net/Dublin.aspx. BTW, I used to have a j2ee book. It was about 1,300 pages. About 1/3 was configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like the Windows Application Server Extensions project?

http://www.microsoft.com/net/Dublin.aspx

BTW, just about everything you want to be "scalable" is covered by using IIS as a host.  Project Dublin and related projects (like [WAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734677.aspx)) are in development now.